# Google plus API shutdown today, which alternative can be used to authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I am using `rails-4`, and have used `OAuth-2` for authentication with `Google+ API`, for which the following gems are used, in my app:

1. omniauth-oauth2
2. omniauth-google-oauth2

I have received the following prior email notice:

> On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut down 
>   completely. This will be a progressive shutdown, with API calls starting 
>   to intermittently fail as early as January 28, 2019, and OAuth requests > for Google+ scopes starting to intermittently fail as early as February > 15, 2019.

Today, I cannot authenticate, as I get `nil` for `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` after the API received the following piece of code:

```
@user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
```

Please suggest how I can solve this issue, or provide an alternative to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I somehow managed to solve the issue by providing an alternate OpenIdConnect endpoint for user information. Using [source](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery), I replaced:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect
```

with:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
```

I monkey-patched `omniauth-google-oauth2` as follows:

**config/initializers/omniauth_google_oauth2_patch.rb**

```
class OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2 < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
  def raw_info
    @raw_info ||= access_token.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo').parsed
  end
end
```

And it's working great now.